# concatenation of two lines using awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a file with each row having 74 columns. I have been trying to combine these lines if the first and second column matches.
The file looks like below.

```
CHECK_IN|2000000000|MS|XXXX|XXXX|N|34|N|N|N|N|N|Y|N|N|N|N|N|123456|aaaaaa|122333|||||||||||AAAAAA|BBBBBBB|CCCCCCC|||||||||||||||||||1000123|aaaa|N|qwerty||REGISTERED|REGISTERED|REGISTERED|UNREGISTERED|19-05-2015|Video|EDM||||||||||xxxxx
CHECK_IN|2000000000|MS|XXXX|XXXX|N|34|N|Y|N|N|N|N|N|N|N|N|N|345676|Abcgdwejj|aaaaaaa||||||||||||||||||||||||NNNNNNN||||||||1000001|cccccc|N|qyuirt||REGISTERED|REGISTERED|REGISTERED|UNREGISTERED|19-05-2015|Video|EDM||||||||||xxxxx
```

I have used the below script:

```
cat sample_file4.txt | awk -F "|" '{line="";
for(i = 3; i <= NF ;i++)
line = line $i"|";
table[$1"|"$2]=table[$1"|"$2]"|"line;}
END { for (key in table) print key "==>" table[key];}' > output9.txt
```

The record is not appended to the first line.Except the key values, the same line is being repeated.like below

```
1.CHECK_IN|2000000000==>|MS|XXXX|XXXX|N|34|N|N|N|N|N|Y|N|N|N|N|N|123456|aaaaaa|122333|||||||||||AAAAAA|BBBBBBB|CCCCCCC|||||||||||||||||||1000123|aaaa|N|qwerty||REGISTERED|REGISTERED|REGISTERED|UNREGISTERED|19-05-2015|Video|EDM||||||||||xxxxx
2.||MS|XXXX|XXXX|N|34|N|Y|N|N|N|N|N|N|N|N|N|345676|Abcgdwejj|aaaaaaa||||||||||||||||||||||||NNNNNNN||||||||1000001|cccccc|N|qyuirt||REGISTERED|REGISTERED|REGISTERED|UNREGISTERED|19-05-2015|Video|EDM||||||||||xxxxx
```

Please help me to get them onto single line.

Comment: It is coming in the single line. Check this out: http://ideone.com/mfTOZ5

Comment: `combine these lines` is ambiguous - show the expected output for that input.

Answer (score 1):

I would write this:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = "|"}
    { key = $1 SUBSEP $2 }
    !(key in lines) {lines[key]=$0; next}
    {$1=$2=""; line=$0; sub(/^../, "", line); lines[key] = lines[key] FS line}
    END {for (key in lines) {print lines[key]}}
' file
```